# Get auto-Id by time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I use Firebase's `childByAutoId()` (swift) or `.push()` (web) to insert some data in the following format:

```
- events
   - $autoId
      - time:
      - name:
   - $autoId
      - time:
      - name:
```

Where `$autoId` are the randomly generated keys Firebase makes. `time` is the epoch time of when the data was pushed.

I want to allow users to modify each inserted entry's `time`. However, I want to keep the nodes under `events` sorted by their key and by time which Firebase naturally does when you use `.push()`. But if they modify the `time` so that it should actually be in a different order, the entries won't be sorted correctly.

Is there a way to generate an id by the modified `time` so that if it were inserted into `events` it would be in the right order? That way I could just delete the old entry and insert the new one while just duplicating the data.

Answer (score -1):

Since the algorithm for Firebase's push IDs is well documented, you could easily modify the function to generate them based on a specific timestamp.

But I'd recommend instead keeping the necessary values as named properties for each child node. If you need to be able to sort by both creation and modification time, keep two separate properties. That way you won't have to depend on the behavior of the push IDs, but instead use more explicitly named properties to accomplish what you need.